# How to get reference to AzureML Workspace Class in scoring script?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

My scoring function needs to refer to an Azure ML Registered Dataset for which I need a reference to the AzureML Workspace object. When including this in the `init()` function of the scoring script it  gives the following error:

```
 "code": "ScoreInitRestart",
      "message": "Your scoring file's init() function restarts frequently. You can address the error by increasing the value of memory_gb in deployment_config."
```

On debugging the issue is:

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code [REDACTED] to authenticate.
```

How can I resolve this issue without exposing Service Principal Credentials in the scoring script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to reference the workspace in the scoring script. Below is a code snippet of how one can do that -

My deploy script looks like this :

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

#Add python dependencies for the models
scoringenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(
                                   name = "scoringenv",
                                   file_path="config_files/scoring_env.yml"
                                    )
#Create a dictionary to set-up the env variables   
env_variables={'tenant_id':tenant_id,
                        'subscription_id':subscription_id,
                        'resource_group':resource_group,
                        'client_id':client_id,
                        'client_secret':client_secret
                        }
    
scoringenv.environment_variables=env_variables
            
# Configure the scoring environment
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
                                   entry_script='score.py',
                                   source_directory='scripts/',
                                   environment=scoringenv
                                        )
```

What I am doing here is creating an image with the python dependencies(in the scoring_env.yml) and passing a dictionary of the secrets as environment variables. I have the secrets stored in the key-vault.
You may define and pass native python datatype variables.

Now, In my score.py, I reference these environment variables in the init() like this -

```
tenant_id = os.environ.get('tenant_id')
client_id = os.environ.get('client_id')
client_secret = os.environ.get('client_secret')
subscription_id = os.environ.get('subscription_id')
resource_group = os.environ.get('resource_group')
```

Once you have these variables, you may create a workspace object using Service Principal authentication like @Anders Swanson mentioned in his reply.

Another way to resolve this may be by using managed identities for AKS. I did not explore that option.

Hope this helps! Please let me know if you found a better way of solving this.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense. Additionally for other users concerned about including client_secret in Notebook which might be on source control, we can use Key Vault to refer to these values.

Answer (score 2):

Does your `score.py` include a `Workspace.get()` with `auth=InteractiveAuthentication` call? You should swap it to `ServicePrincipalAuthentication` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.authentication.serviceprincipalauthentication?view=azure-ml-py)) to which you pass your credentials ideally through environment variables.

```py
import os
   from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication

   svc_pr_password = os.environ.get("AZUREML_PASSWORD")

   svc_pr = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(
       tenant_id="my-tenant-id",
       service_principal_id="my-application-id",
       service_principal_password=svc_pr_password)


   ws = Workspace(
       subscription_id="my-subscription-id",
       resource_group="my-ml-rg",
       workspace_name="my-ml-workspace",
       auth=svc_pr
       )

   print("Found workspace {} at location {}".format(ws.name, ws.location))
```

Comment: Yes, my concern is about exposing SPN credentials in my repository. How can I set credentials ideally through environment variables while deploying using AZ CLI? That is, the function will run in an AKS cluster. How do I set the environment variables of the cluster? Or are you referring to some other workflow.

Comment: @AnirbanSaha totally see your point about passing environment variables to the cluster. I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I couldn't find a doc for it. Let me ask around...

Comment: this is the official documentation:
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

You can get the workspace object directly from your run.

```
from azureml.core.run import Run
ws = Run.get_context().experiment.workspace
```

Comment: This again works for training scripts. However, for the scoring script, there is no Run that is created.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same challenge. As you are mentioning AML Datasets, I assume an AML Batch Endpoint is suitable to your scenario. The scoring script for a batch endpoint is meant to receive a list of files as input. When invoking the batch endpoint, you can pass (among the others) AML Datasets (consider that an endpoint is deployed in the context of an AML workspace). Have a look to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-batch-with-rest#run-batch-scoring).

Comment: No, I was more interested in getting a reference to this Dataset and use the content in a regular scoring endpoint (meant to serve requests in real-time)

Answer (score 0):

**When Running on AML Compute CLuster use the following code**

```
from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineRun as Run

run = Run.get_context()
run.experiment.workspace
ws = run.experiment.workspace
```

**Note: This works only when you run on AML Cluster**

`Run.get_context()` gets the conext of total AML cluster from that object we can extract workspace context which allows you to authenticate AML workspace with AML cluster